# SXA Dynamic Placeholders not working when creating multiple placeholders inside of a single rendering

Tags: sxa, presentation, placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

I am currently working in Sitecore 9.1.1 with SXA 1.9. I am trying to build out a Rendering Variant that points to a datasource item with sub-items. These sub-items are child items to the datasource for the Rendering, and are gotten through a RenderingVariant/Query. Then rendered out with standard SXA Field Renders. Rendering each sub-item with a dynamic placeholder that should allow a Content Author to optionally add a component next to it.

The Placeholder Key points to a Presentation/Placeholder item. I have followed the Sitecore Documentation for building a dynamic placeholder in SXA found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-dynamic-placeholder-to-a-rendering-variant.html
However, when the component gets rendered out the placeholders are not unique thus once I put a component into one place holder it gets applied to them all.

Rendering Variant Structure:
[image: Rendering Variant Structure]

Placeholder Settings: 
[image: Placeholder Settings]

Rendering with Placeholders as built in EE:
[image: Rendering with Placeholders as built in EE]

[image: Rendering with Placeholders as built in EE]

Any ideas or possible solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the wildcard * on the end of the placeholder key within your rendering variant? IE. Use "historymedia*" in the rendering variant deatails field?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dave. Yes, I have tried that as well, and it did not work either.

Comment: Just an update on this question. I currently have a ticket open with Sitecore and will add any updates here when I get a response.

Comment: Do you have any updates on this BlakeKnox? I'm currently facing the same issue... :(

Comment: have you find any solution for the above issue ?

Comment: Hey Bala, unfortunately no. The response from Sitecore is that this would be unsupported. They suggested changing they way we are building up the rendering. We found a work around that was very specific to our solution by inheriting the necessary fields on the datasource items. Then using SXA's VarientComponentFeild to render the item conditionally based off of the fields.To make it work you would have to build a custom implementation of the rendering and implicitly assign very unique seed values to the Dynamic PH. I have done this before, but for our solution we were okay with our workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `IsRenderingsWithDynamicPlaceholders: true` in `Controller` or `View Renderings`.

[image]